# Passing Nil Arguments to Lua Script on Redis?

Tags: lua, redis

I have a lua redis script that I want to pass some nil arguments to in ARGV. I figured the following would work:

```
redis-cli EVAL "$(cat some_script.lua)" 3 key1 key2 key 3 nil nil 4
```

In that case, I'd expect ARGV[1] = ARGV[2] = nil. Instead, they seem to be set to `'nil'` (the string) inside lua, so when I do something like:

```
if ARGV[1] then return ARGV[1] end
```

I get `'nil'` returned to me.

How do I properly pass nils to Lua?

Comment: Don't pass anything and it'll be `nil` inside the program. Otherwise, you'll always receive a string.

Comment: @hjpotter92 yes, but the question (and the example) are for when there's a non-nil argument after the nil argument. In that case, how would I pass nothing for the arguments that should be nil? See the example.

Answer (score 4):

No, command line arguments will always be a `string`, even if you pass arguments like this:

```
lua script.lua "test argument" "" "end"
```

You will still get

```
argv[1] = "test argument"
argv[2] = ""   --empty string
argv[3] = "end"
```

In this case, argv[4] = `nil`, but I don't think this is what you want, as the program expects a non-nil argument at the end.

So why not set some flag strings to stand for `nil` in your script, e.g, use the string "nil" as a flag, so you can test in your script:

```
if argv[1] ~= "nil" then return argv[1] end
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, but I figured there must be a way to just pass nil in the middle. It seems really dysfunctional not to have that when you want to allow people to use variables set to nil.

Comment: @Eli Think this way: Lua is implemented with C, C passes `argv` as an array of strings. If you really need to, maybe changing Lua source code `getargs` can do the job.